# identifier "numIDs" is undefined while inside of scope

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined

I am coding a small app thats supposed to take a string of numbers from a text file then save them into an array, and finally print the array through iteration, the file should be in this format:

```
10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The first number being the amount of numbers or "IDs" that should be in the array, the rest being the elements of this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream test;
    test.open("test.txt");
    string s;
    getline(test, s);
    int numtest = s[0];
    for (int  i = 0; i < numtest; i++) {
        string currLine;
        getline(test, currLine);
        int numIDs = currLine[0];
        int arrayIDs[numIDs];
        for (int j = 2, k = 0; j < numIDs; j += 2, k++) {
            arrayIDs[k] = currLine[j];
        }
    }
    test.close();
    for (int i = 0; i <= numIDs; i++) {
        cout << arrayIDs[i];
    }
}
```

However, i get the errors

> `identifier "numIDs" is undefined`
>
> `identifier "arrayIDs" is undefined`

On lines 22 and 23 respectively, though i dont know why, to my understanding since these 2 are variables there shouldnt be any problems with an `#include`, and are both inside the `main()` function, so i dont get why they would be undefined.

Comment: Those items exist only for the life of your first `for` loop. Your second loop is referencing names it cannot see.

Comment: `numIDs` is defined inside the scope of the `for` loop. It doesn't exist outside it. You need to move it outside the loop if you want to use it after the loop has ended. `i <= numIDs` would index the array out of bounds, and `arrayIDs[k] = currLine[j];` will give you the ascii value of the numbers, not the numbers themselves. `currLine[j] - '0'` could work, but your solution is fragile. Just read the numbers directly into the array using `>>`. A `stringstream` can help with that.

Comment: You might also consider a `std::vector` instead of `int arrayIDs[numIDs];`. Variable length arrays are not standard C++ and will not work on all compilers.

Comment: As an aside, the line `numIDs = curLine[1]` is not going to result in the value `10` from your sample data line. That will get you only the first character, which is `'1'`. Since it is a character type, `numIDs` will have the value of the character representation, which in ASCII is 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables placed inside a loop will not be visible outside the loop. So to fix your problem, declare numIDs outside the loop instead of in it. Also, from the looks of it, you would want to put the second loop in the first.
Original:

```
int numtest = s[0];
for (int  i = 0; i < numtest; i++) {
    string currLine;
    getline(test, currLine);
    int numIDs = currLine[0];
    int arrayIDs[numIDs];
    for (int j = 2, k = 0; j < numIDs; j += 2, k++) {
        arrayIDs[k] = currLine[j];
    }
}
```

Revised:

```
int numtest = s[0];
int numIDs = 0;
for (int  i = 0; i < numtest; i++) {
    string currLine;
    getline(test, currLine);
    numIDs = currLine[0];
    int arrayIDs[numIDs];
    for (int j = 2, k = 0; j < numIDs; j += 2, k++) {
        arrayIDs[k] = currLine[j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= numIDs; i++) {
        cout << arrayIDs[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```